# Difference between D-Type Flip-Flop and Edge-Triggered D-Type Flip-Flop

Tags: flipflop, synchronous

I need to create a JK Flip-Flop using a D Flip-Flop, a 2-to-1 line MUX and an inverter.  I wasn't really familiar with latches and Flip-Flops, but I understand the difference and how Flip-Flops are edge triggered with a clock pulse whereas latches are instantaneous with input changes.  Now when I was doing some digging into D-type Flip-Flops, I came across two different representations that I'm having a hard time differentiating.  The first is very straightforward and seems to be the standard representation.

[image: D-Flip-Flop]

This computes fine for me.  I can trace and follow it and fully understand how it works. Most common name I could find for it was simply D-Type Flip Flop.

However when I look further, I cannot differentiate between the name of the previous D-type Flip-Flop and this one:

[image: Also A D-Type Flip-Flop]

Everywhere I look this one is defined as Edge-Triggered D-Type Flip-Flop, but I thought where a synchronous circuit uses a clock changes were always edge-triggered? Can someone please explain the difference and how to go about tracing the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is not master-slave; you would have to cascade two copies of that circuit (with the clock inverted between them) to get the same functionality as the second circuit, which is indeed a master-slave (edge-triggered) flip-flop.